# SQL Server - How to check a row can be deleteable before deleting

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, delete-row, sqlexception

How can I check a row can be delete-able before deleting the row? It is like developing a new function CanDelete(RowID).

I have REFERENCE of this tables in another table for some of the rows.

One way I can do it is by catching the exception. Is there any better way?

Comment: Fundamentally, you can't know in advance whether a transaction will succeed or not. Even if no row in the other table is referencing the given row, another row could be added which does reference it in between the time you check and the time you attempt to delete. Having said that, you can write a query that counts the number of rows in the other table that reference the row you're interested in deleting, but this is not a robust solution (and may be slower than just handling the exception in the first place).

Comment: Write the delete as a stored procedure or Instead Of Delete trigger with logic to check foreign keys before deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your requirement is you do not want to delete a row is it is referenced to from another table.

I would not leave this up to the c# code. What if another application is developed that does the delete or someone access the database directly.

First you should set up a [delete rule](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/) on the relationship . Secondarily you could write a trigger to check before deleting and Handel it in there. Finally you could write you delete statement with a not exist for example

```
DELETE from TableA where ID in (select ID from tableA a left outer join tableB b on a.ID = b.ID where b.ID is NULL)
```